# Minimum edge-weighted directed subgraph in polynomial time

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms, combinatorial-optimization, directed-graphs

I am looking for an algorithm with polynomial complexity where, given a strongly connected edge-weighted digraph I can find the minimal subgraph which connects some root vertex v to a known set of other vertices.

As an example, given a strongly connected edge-weighted digraph with vertices labeled a-z, I want to find the minimal subgraph rooted at node j that includes nodes b, f, g, and p.

In my case I am going to be using this to determine an optimal pipeline for doing image manipulation (I already have a strongly connected edge-weighted digraph for this application).

Comment: Yes, thanks @MaxAlekseyev

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an instance of the Directed Steiner Network Problem and as such it's solvable in time $|V(G)|^{O(|T|)}$ as proved by [Feldman & Ruhl (2006)](https://doi.org/10.1137/S0097539704441241), where $G$ is the given graph and $T\subset V(G)$ is the given subset of vertices (terminals).

Comment: I think this is the best answer to the question as presented, however due to the time complexity of the Feldman & Ruhl solution with my values for G = (V, E), I believe an approximation approach similar to the one described by @RobPratt is probably what I will go for.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to implement a specialized algorithm, you can solve the problem via  mixed integer linear programming as follows.  Let $T$ be the set of terminal nodes.  For each directed arc $(i,j)\in A$, let nonnegative variable $x_{ij}$ be the flow from $i$ to $j$, and let binary variable $y_{ij}$ indicate whether arc $(i,j)$ is used.  The problem is to minimize $$\sum_{(i,j)\in A} c_{ij} y_{ij}$$ subject to
\begin{align}
\sum_{(i,j)\in A} x_{ij} - \sum_{(j,i)\in A} x_{ji} &= 
\begin{cases}
|T| &\text{if $i=v$} \\
-1 &\text{if $i\in T$} \\
0 &\text{otherwise}
\end{cases} \\
x_{ij} &\le |T|y_{ij}
\end{align}